# AudioSource Unity 5, нормальное использование

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код который выводит звук один раз и показывает картинку, когда сделаешь 5 щелчков мышкой.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

public float gts = 0;
public GameObject myOverlay; 
public AudioClip impact; 
AudioSource audio1; 



void Start () {
    audio1 = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    myOverlay.SetActive(false);
    RequestInterstitial();

}
void OnMouseDown() { gts++; }
void Update () {
if (gts == 5) { dog(); }
    if(gts > 5) { dog(); }}
void dog()
   {


    if (audio1.isPlaying)
    {
        myOverlay.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        audio1.PlayOneShot(impact);
        myOverlay.SetActive(true);

   }
```

В таком виде код работает. Хотел добавить новую функциональность – включить на AudioSource фоновую музыку. 
Она тоже работает, но тогда при 5 кликах мышкой новый звук(который impact) не выводится, так как мы попадаем под условие audio1.isPlaying.
Если убрать условие а просто поставить

```
void dog()
{

    audio1.Stop();
    audio1.PlayOneShot(impact);
    myOverlay.SetActive(true);


}
```

То получаем что Play.OneShot пытается воспроизвестись, первая миллисекунда, а потом её обрывает, вероятно наш же audio1.Stop();, звучит как непрерывный шум в итоге.

Делал несколько разных попыток с паузами, анпаузами, стопами и прочее. Всё равно, какого то корректного звучания с одного аудио источника добиться не получается.

Вопрос в следующем – надо, чтобы играла фоновая музыка, иногда(по условию, допустим 5 кликов мышкой) она бы прерывалась и играла бы другая музыка, 1 раз. Потом, по другому условию, играл еще какой нибудь PlayOneShot. Потом продолжала играть фоновая, в loop-е.  Как это реализовать?

Comment: Мне кажется вы пытаетесь навесить много ответственности на выполнение одному ресурсу. Не стоит заставлять объект и играть фоновую музыку и небольшой эффект воспроизводить и пироги печь и убирать в комнате и телепортировать в другую галактику........Добавьте на сцену объект также с `AudioSource`, который будет ответственнен за фоновую музыку на сцене..запустить `Play`  и пусть идет или сменяется когда одна мелодия закончилась.......а ваш пес пусть только гавкает или издает кратковременные звуки через `PlayOneShot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился господа. Надо было банально обнулять переменные после использования, чтобы не вызывался каждый наш звук каждый update.
Вот старый кусок кода с ошибкой.

```
 void Update () {
 if (gts == 5) { dog(); }
if(gts > 5) { dog(); }}
```

Переделанный кусок кода.

```
void Update () {
 if (gts == 5) { gts = 0; dog(); }
if(gts > 5) { gts = 0; dog(); }}
```